# I want to save data in excel sheet using mvc5 but each time it replaces the file, while I want to add on the previous

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, ole

How to append data in excel sheet? I save it but it replaces the file. I want to add, not deleting previous data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult excel(Student st)      
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook myworkbook = app.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    //  Excel.Worksheet mysheet = myworkbook.ActiveSheet ; 
    ///////write header in excel
    mysheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
    mysheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
    mysheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Email";
    mysheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Age";
    mysheet.Cells[1, 5] = "PassWord";
    mysheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Confirm";       

    int row = 2;       

    //putting received data from create action in excel sheet.
    mysheet.Cells[row, 1] = st.ID;
    mysheet.Cells[row, 2] = st.Name;
    mysheet.Cells[row, 3] = st.E_Mail;
    mysheet.Cells[row, 4] = st.Age;
    mysheet.Cells[row, 5] = st.PassWord;
    mysheet.Cells[row, 6] = st.Confirm;


    // save the data 
    myworkbook.SaveAs("f:\\myfirstexcelmvc.xls");
    myworkbook.Close();

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myworkbook);
    app.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
}
```